# How to compare a schema defined in a file with actual schema running on DB?

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a PostgreSQL DB and want to compare the schema defined in `schema.sql` with the schema that is created on the DB on a regular basis. I.e. to verify that no manual changes on the remote are applied or that `schema.sql` actually reflects what's running on the DB.

What I'm currently doing is roughly:

- create a dump from `schema.sql` using `pg_virtualenv`:

```sh
$ pg_virtualenv sh -c 'psql -U $PGDATABASE -f schema.sql
$ pg_dump --schema-only --no-comments --no-owner --no-privileges --schema=public -U $PGDATABASE -f schema_local.sql'
```

- create a dump from the remote

```sh
$ pg_dump --schema-only --no-comments --no-owner --no-privileges --schema=public -U $PGREMOTE -f schema_upstream.sql
```

- strip out comments, `SET`, emtpy lines, etc. and `diff` them

```sh
$ diff -u <(grep -Ev '^--|^SET|^$$' schema_local.sql) <(grep -Ev '^--|^SET|^$$' schema_upstream.sql)
```

That works reasonably well and I can easily spot schema changes in the diff if they occur. But the solution seems a bit hacky and I wonder if there's a better way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Cannot you just revoke rights on the schema to make sure nobody can change it? Another way without revoking the rights might be to compare the contents of the catalog tables/views between both schemas.

Comment: No this is not about restricting rights. The devs on that DB are expected to make manual tweaks from time to time, but the changes should be reflected properly in the `schema.sql`

Comment: I think what you are doing is perfectly fine. Alternatively you can use open source Meld tool instead of diff command for file comparison.